# How to create non-repetitive nodes with relations in neo4j efficiently?

Tags: java, neo4j

I need to create 50,000 nodes (`:Person`) with some relationship with 50 nodes (`:office`), it is guaranteed that `:office` elements does not have repetitive elements, but `:Person` has.

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :office(rc)
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(numDoc)
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV FROM 
"file:///path/to/file" AS csvLine
MATCH (x:office{ rc:"345421"})
MERGE (n:Person { numDoc: toint(csvLine[1]) })
CREATE (n) -[:Afil]-> (x)
```

It actually works, but it takes so much time (around 2 hours). I would like to know a efficiently way to make this query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make the spelling / capitalization consistent.
Try to use Neo4j 2.3.0

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Office(rc);

CREATE INDEX ON :Person(numDoc);

// make sure the indexes are online

:schema await

MATCH (x:Office{ rc:"345421"})
LOAD CSV FROM  "file:///path/to/file" AS csvLine
MERGE (n:Person { numDoc: toInt(csvLine[1]) })
CREATE (n) -[:Afil]-> (x);
```

If you only create 50k people and 50k relationships you don't need periodic commit. And then you can match the office once upfront and not for every row.

You can check your query by prepending it with EXPLAIN if it uses the indexes you created.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed I was Matching for every row!! When create and index It store the nodes in some data structure to make matching faster? or does something different.

Comment: If you would like to improve the performance you should use a batch importer

Answer (score 1):

Have you got indexes in place for the MATCH/MERGE clauses?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Office(rc)
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(numDoc)
```

Also, it seems to me that a TX size of 500 might be too small.
Have you tried increasing it to 10000?

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
```

Another thing you might want to review is your memory settings. Have you got enough pagecache and heap for Neo4j to run efficiently?

Comment: Hmm so using the indexes is the only way to reduce the time? How indexes reduce the time? Does it make some kind of hash or some data structure to store the data?

Comment: Which version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: @AlessandroNegro 2.3.0 I started using it since Monday.